# How can I exclude those rows that contain specific substring/word BUT containing another specific substring?

Tags: google-bigquery, contains

I have a data where there is a column where a child is given either a measles vaccine, polio vaccine or both. So a cell can contain "MEASLES given", POLIO given" or MEASLES and POLIO" given but in different formats. I can extract those given with measles using the CONTAINS_SUBST(---, "MEASLES) and those given with POLIO. BUT I cannot determine if they are given measles only without polio, polio only without measles. Here is my working code.

```
WITH measles_table AS
(SELECT
*
FROM
----

WHERE
CONTAINS_SUBSTR(vaccine, "MEASLES") AND date_of_report>="2023-05-01"

)
SELECT
region,
COUNT(number) as total_measles
COUNTIF(seious="NO") as non_serious_total,
COUNTIF(serious="YES") as serious_total,

FROM
measles_table

GROUP BY
region
```

I am not sure if there is a function that can be used like NOT CONTAINS_SUBSTR. I've been looking through google but it suggests that I need to make another WITH table and it will mess up my code since I just want to get the numbers.
I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to achieve, you could use the NOT LIKE operator in SQL to check if a column does not contain a specific substring. Would something like this achieve your desired results?

```
WITH vaccine_table AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    ---
  WHERE
    vaccine LIKE '%MEASLES%' OR vaccine LIKE '%POLIO%' -- Filter for rows containing measles or polio
    AND date_of_report >= '2023-05-01'
)

SELECT
  region,
  COUNT(number) AS total_measles,
  COUNTIF(seious = 'NO') AS non_serious_total,
  COUNTIF(serious = 'YES') AS serious_total,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN vaccine LIKE '%MEASLES%' AND vaccine NOT LIKE '%POLIO%' THEN 1 END) AS measles_only_total,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN vaccine LIKE '%POLIO%' AND vaccine NOT LIKE '%MEASLES%' THEN 1 END) AS polio_only_total,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN vaccine LIKE '%MEASLES%' AND vaccine LIKE '%POLIO%' THEN 1 END) AS measles_and_polio_total
FROM
  vaccine_table
GROUP BY
  region;
```